# Date Range Excel Formula That Uses Contents of Selected Cel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a function in excel gives me data based on a chosen date range

`=SUMIF('2018'!D:D,"="&$B$1, '2018'!U:U)`

The code above is working well except there is one problem: I have to change the `2018` part every year by hand.

Is there any way to allow that to also be **changed by using the contents of another cell**?

**Something like**

`=SUMIF('B2'!D:D,"="&$B$1, 'B2'!U:U)`

I know that is a string but I've tried a bunch of combinations and can't figure it out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps look at INDIRECT.

Comment: play around with the 'indirect' formula: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261  keep in mind, it's expensive and not something you should use across the board.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Import Sheet name in `C1` and try:

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT($C$1& "!D:D"),"="&$B$1,INDIRECT($C$1& "!U:U"))`

Image:

[image]

2. Use current year

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&YEAR(TODAY())&"'!D:D"),"="&$B$1,INDIRECT("'"&YEAR(TODAY())&"'!U:U"))`